# Select Multiple Columns from Multiple Tables using Separate Where Conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using mySQL for a while, but have not really wanted to be this efficient till now. I currently have the following code:

```
SELECT `page_name` AS manufacturer_name
FROM `manufacturers`
WHERE `id` = '$manufacturers_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT `page_name` AS series_name
FROM `series`
WHERE `id` = '$series_id'
```

Unfortunately this is not doing what I want, it is selecting the right information for me, but it is putting it all under just one column name: manufacturer_name. How do I modify this to select the page name from manufacturers and series separately? This is the current output I am getting:

```
manufacturer_name
my_manufacturer_name
my_series_name
```

This is what I would like to have as output (Note: I just used this as a column separator: |):

```
   manufacturer_name | series_name
my_manufacturer name | my_series_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your results contain only single row then use

```
select 
(
  SELECT `page_name` AS manufacturer_name
  FROM `manufacturers`
  WHERE `id` = '$manufacturers_id'
) as manufacturer_name,
(
  SELECT `page_name` AS series_name
  FROM `series`
  WHERE `id` = '$series_id'
) as series_name
```

Another possibility with `UNION` is

```
SELECT `page_name` AS manufacturer_name, null as series_name
FROM `manufacturers`
WHERE `id` = '$manufacturers_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT null, `page_name`
FROM `series`
WHERE `id` = '$series_id'
```

but this returns 2 rows.